# How do you prove mirrors aren't literally parallel universes?

Tags: science-based, universe, alternate-reality

### See [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46016/how-do-you-prove-that-mirrors-arent-parallel-universes) on Puzzling SE if you still want to answer.

---

"*Each mirror is a world of its own*", Joe explains.
"*Joe, that's bullshit! Mirrors are just mirrors!*" Rita proclaims.

**Joe proceeds to lay out the following Laws of Mirror Universes:**

> 1. For each **one** orientation of a mirror (rotated spherically or in 3D space) there
>      is exactly **one** universe perfectly symmetrical to our own.
> 2. There are infinite orientations possible in a sphere, so there are **infinite** universes parallel to our own
> 3. Every universe began at the same time and progressed in the exact same way, with the exception of being "flipped" as we observe in a
>      reflection. That means **we are nothing special**.
> 4. The **line of symmetry** in each case is **defined by the mirror** itself.
> 5. Changing the orientation of a mirror links to another exact replica of that mirror universe - they are all [congruent to each
>      other through transitivity](http://ceemrr.com/Geometry1/Transitive/Transitive_print.html)
> 6. We cannot exchange matter into these universes because for every **one** particle that attempts to cross the threshhold, exactly **one** congruent particle meets it at the barrier.
> 7. "**Weak Reflectional Attraction**" accounts for substances "stuck" to each other across the threshhold. This is why mirrors can be dirty
>
>    - the boundary has a slight pull that makes dirt, etc stay on the plane of the mirror instead of falling as if there was simply air.
> 8. **Warped** boundaries such as funhouse mirrors or reflections in water serve only as windows; they must be flat and rigid to allow
>      actual interaction.
> 9. The **medium** of the mirror (metal, etc) **moderates heat** transfer, which is why you don't feel immediate warmth when you touch
>      a mirror with your hand.

---

"*Joe*," says Rita, "*Your 'theory' doesn't account for* this *.*"
Rita picks up a **household object** and demonstrates why mirrors are simple reflections of light, and nothing more.

Her demonstration produces results that would be *different* if there were multiple, congruent universes bound by mirrors (for example hitting the mirror with something that should have gone through if there were actually an alt. univ. on the other side)

### What does Rita do?

Comment: She uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor and gives Joe a good shave.

Comment: This sounds more like a riddle for puzzling stackexchange.

Comment: @Philipp I considered that, but it's based in scientific ways to demonstrate the properties of something - all the while woven through a story - so I figured this place would be a good middleground

Comment: @Karl Then Rita could also use Occam's razor to cut the fabric of reality - "it's simpler to say nothing exists" but alas, that may not work

Comment: She picks up a flyer on which is written 'the burden of proof lies with the accuser' and says "prove your hypothesis Joe".

Comment: Interesting question but sorry, it's definitely off topic for worldbuilding as it's currently phrased. At the moment the only place I think it might fit is puzzling.

Comment: There is no proof or disproof for Joes hypothesis, as long as he constructs his mirror hypothesis as exactly describing our observable reality. Ordinary photon physics are however a much more convenient way to describe reallity, which is where Occams razor comes into action. *Snip.*

Comment: QED describes how a mirror will work, along with all electric, magnetic, optical, radio, etc. phenomina. Other tests on the material of the mirror will show the conductivity, and reflecting light of different wavelengths will cause electric fields to penetrate to different depths, which can be illustrated by looking at different thicknesses of coating, evencent wqves, etc.  The mirror is reflecting via QED, so what would the mirror universe be doing?

Comment: Answer: they shoot a particle beam through the mirror, preferably at an angle away from the normal. X-Ray, Gamma, neutrinos, neutrons... any one that normally passes through matter and is not reflected by the mirror surface will do. If the mirror was a window, the beam would not come out the back of it. And the beam would also appear to be reflected as the corresponding beam from the other side passes into our universe.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Not convincing. Only some part of the light spectrum is transmitted into the mirror universe. Everything else just passes though the mirror material in *our* world. Same for a partially reflective mirror.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Smash the mirror

"Joe, you need to get a job"

Comment: +1 because it's funny, but I tried to account for this - see Joe's Law #2. Each new shard would be another link.